# Try storing the view state in the session cause any issue?

Tags: c#

I have met with a scenario that, when the view state size increases, the browser can't handle the view state hidden field values.So it truncates the values of view state and causes a "view state corrupted" error message.So I had to maintain the view state using the following override methods.

```
    protected override object LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium()
    {
        return Session["_ViewState"];
    }
    protected override void SavePageStateToPersistenceMedium(object viewState)
    {
        Session["_ViewState"] = viewState;
    }
```

Will this cause any issue?

Comment: sounds like a not very good idea: I suggest you read this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx

Comment: Thank you, @Jocke.But I had the scenario which I have mentioned, which was badly affecting my page.I got the solution from :[https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/829743#top]

Comment: Okey, good find! Good luck!